# Error In getting data from DataTableReader

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access-2007, oledb

as title say's im not being able to get my data from datatable, it's because im using innerjoin , if i only use one table it work's fine, as soon as i put inner join it gives me this error :

seems like the error its in sql sentence, because it don't return any value to datareader.

"System.InvalidOperationException: 'O DataTableReader é inválido para o DataTable atual ''.'"

**here goes the code**

```
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM TOTAIS INNER JOIN FAT_PRODS ON TOTAIS.ID_FAT=FAT_PRODS.ID_FAT WHERE FAT_PRODS.ID_FAT=" + DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString + ""
    Dim dadosretornados As System.Data.DataTableReader = buscadadosacess(sql)
    If dadosretornados.HasRows Then
        While dadosretornados.Read
            MsgBox(dadosretornados("ID_PROD"))
        End While

    End If
```

**here is the function buscadados**

```
 Function buscadadosacess(sql As String)
    oConn.ConnectionString = strConn
    oConn.Open()

    If oConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        ACommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, oConn)
        'define um dataAdapter
        AAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        AAdapter.SelectCommand = ACommand
        'define e preenche um DataTable com os dados
        ATabela = New DataTable()
        AAdapter.Fill(ATabela)
        ' associar campos a base de dados
        xy = ATabela.CreateDataReader
        ' Ler da tabela
        'linha = ACommand.ExecuteReader
    End If

    'Tipo de dados incorrecto na expressão de critérios.'

    Return xy

End Function
```

thanks guys <3

Comment: Try with: `"SELECT * FROM TOTALS  ...`?

Comment: thanks for the awnser, totais is the name of my table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was just a "." in the SQL Setence, here it goes the SQL SENTENCE Correct:

```
        Dim sql As String = "select totais.id_fat,totais.valor_siva,totais.iva,totais.valortotal,totais.data,totais.nome_cliente,fat_prods.id_fat,fat_prods.id_prod,fat_prods.quantidade,fat_prods.preco,fat_prods.id_cliente,fat_prods.descricao from totais INNER JOIN fat_prods ON totais.id_fat=fat_prods.id_fat WHERE totais.id_fat=" + valor.ToString + ""
```

thanks for all the help